# Need help finding solution of equation coinciding with span of matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus

Let $a1, a2$ and $a3$ be some vectors. 
$a1= \{5,-5,3,1\}$ , $a2= \{0,-2,-1,-4\}$,  $a3= \{0,0,-3,3\}$ 
Question is to find a linear equation in $[x,y,z,u]$ where the solution coincides with $span \{a1,a2,a3 \} $.

Thank you very much for any help/tips.

Comment: what is the forth coordinate of $a3$?

Comment: sorry, a3={0,0,-3,3}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $a_1, a_2, a_3$ and present them in a matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
5 & -5 & 3 & 1\\
0 & -2 & -1 & -4\\
0 & 0 & -3 & 3
\end{array}\left|\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right.\right]$$

after preforming Gaussian elimination:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{33}{10}\\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{5}{2}\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]$$

and this is the span.

Comment: Thanks for helping me find the span of the three vectors. From here, to answer my assignment question, do I just use simultaneous equations to find x,y,z and u?

Comment: x+(33/10)u = 0  ;   y + (5/2) = 0   ;    z + (-1)u = 0

Comment: you'll get: 

$x + \frac{33}{10}u =0$ 
$ y + \frac{5}{2}u = 0$
$z -u = 0$, so $(x, y, z, u) = sp \left(\frac{-33}{10}, \frac{-5}{2}, 1, 1 \right)$

Comment: @JenCJB hope that answers your question.

Comment: Yes, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The equation will be of the form $ax+by+cz+du=0$ (why?). Plug in the coordinates of each of the given vectors and you’ll end up with a system of linear equations in the unknown coefficients that I assume you know how to solve. Note that the solution is not unique: both sides of the above equation can be multiplied by any nonzero scalar without changing its solution set.